# Looking for the title of an early 2000s cartoon involving a kid with a watch or similar trinket fighting monsters (not Ben 10)

Tags: story-identification, animated-series

One of my first memories is from an episode of a show I watched as a kid.
It was about a young boy fighting some sort of slime monster in the sewers.

It was in the early 2000s in German TV. We usually just get the dubbed versions of what Americans get to watch about 4-6 years later.

I remember that the main character was from a line of monster hunters and he had a talking naked cat as a mentor. I also believe it turned out later the cat was evil.

In the show the kid started off with little powers but unlocked them by defeating monsters.

Comment: I have marked your question as a duplicate. This does not mean it's a bad question question, just that we've had it before.

Answer (score 3):

Never mind I found it myself!!!! It was called ***[Monster Allergy](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0850641/)*** (2005–2009).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monster_Allergy_(TV_series)):

> *Monster Allergy* is based on the [comic book series of the same name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monster_Allergy). The series follows young boy Ezekiel Zick (nicknamed Zick) who suffers from various allergies and has the ability to see the invisible monsters that live among us. Along with help of his best friend, Elena Potato and his talking cat, Timothy, Zick hopes to hone his powers to one day become a Monster Tamer just like his dad, Zobedja Zick.

Comment: Great!  Can you [edit] in a few more details, like year released, plot synopsis?

Comment: :) And don't forget to accept your self-answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour]. As a self-answer, you won't be able to complete the process for another 43 hours (48 hours after asking), but clicking early will let you know how much time is left.